# Can't compile React component from builder format via Mitosis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, mitosis

I've installed Mitosis on my Node.js project, create the directory `build` for output files and create the input file `component.jsx` with the code from the link https://github.com/builderio/mitosis#at-a-glance

If I run the command

```
mitosis compile -t react --out=build/myCustomName.js component.jsx
```

everything works fine.

But when I paste the JSX code into the left column of their live compiler by the link https://mitosis.builder.io, compile it to JSON, then copy-paste the output JSON code into the file component.json and run the command

```
mitosis compile -t react -f builder --out=build/myCustomName.js component.json
```

I receive the file myCustomName.js with the following code only

```
import { useContext } from "react";

export default function MyComponent(props) {
  return <></>;
}
```

Why? And how to resolve the issue?

ps. as I understand input format `builder` means their JSON, right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I see that the input format `builder` is also JSON, but it's not the same than `JSON` output format at the mitosis.builder.io. The issue is resolved.